# How do I pass the parameter of whichever list object I click on?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/userList",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if (!data) alert("ERROR")
        else{
            for (let j=0;j<data.length;j++) {
                user = data[j];
                console.log(data[j]);
                $("#userList").append("<button> <a href='javaScript:getUserProfile("  + data[j] +  ")'>" + data[j] + "</button>");
            }
        }
    } ,
    dataType: "json"
});
```

It keeps saying data[j] is undefined whenever i try to pass it in. I have done print statements and such but I can't find the root of the issue.

Comment: What does the `console.log(data)` output?  What is `data.length`?

Comment: as per your question, it seems you wanna pass the variable that you click on, so you should add a setting `data: whateverYouWantToPass` to the ajax

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/userList",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    if (!data)
        alert("ERROR")
    else{
        for (j=0;j<data.length;j++) {
            var user = data[j];
            console.log(user);
            $("#userList").append("<button> <a href='javaScript:getUserProfile("  + user +  ")'>" + user + "</button>");
        }
    }
  }
});
```

Also, make sure that the url is correct. Looks like is not correct....